# CakePHP favicon in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, cakephp, favicon

I'm using this code to display favicon on CakePHP's website:

```
echo $this->Html->meta('favicon.ico', $this->webroot.'img/favicon.ico',array('type' => 'icon'));
```

It works pretty on all browsers... except Internet Explorer. What's strange for me is that when I type URL address to favicon, I can download it in all browsers however in IE I'm getting something like this:

```
h(  @  ûø÷GöëâÿÜµ“ÿÍSÿÒ and so on...
```

Anybody had similar problem to this?

--
There is linux on the server side. I'm using IE9.